# Flex layout problem with <!DOCTYPE html> and <input type="text">

Tags: html, css, quirks-mode

The desired result is to place an input field and some text on a line, having the text take up all the space it can in the viewport without overlapping the text.

Chrome, Safari and FireFox all agree, so the logical conclusion is that I've been relying on "almost standards mode" in some way I don't realize. But the behavior with "DOCTYPE html" seemingly defies reason.

Fortunately, I could minimize it to a barebones example. With "DOCTYPE html", the input field overlaps the following text. Without it, it behaves as I would expect.

```html
<div style="display: flex; flex-flow: row, nowrap">
  <div style="width: 100%">
    <!-- "width" here doesn't help or hinder-->
    <input type="text" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div>
    OK?
  </div>
</div>
```

What's going on?

Comment: The line wrap makes my comment unclear. The width property on the DIV element doesn't affect the result either way. The width on the INPUT element is necessary for the effect I want.

Comment: Have you tried to add box-sizing to all elements? Or at least only the ones interacting (div, input)? `* {
box-sizing: border-box;
}`

Comment: In my actual use case I have "body { box-sizing: border-box; }" but it doesn't affect this issue.

Comment: Well yes, because that adds only to the body. You either add to all elements or the ones you want specifically. If you inspect in browser if the element doesn't have box-sizing that means the body one didn't inherit.

Comment: I should leave well enough alone and stop editing the question. In the code that's there now, the width is necessary on the div. With "flex: 1 1 auto" it isn't. Anyway, a more minimal frustrating case is to remove all the div styles except the outermost. the box no longer grows, but it still overlaps the text. Why would it do that?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achieve. What does this mean? ->  "having the text take up all the space it can in the viewport without overlapping the text."

Comment: Yosimite, that's it! It sure seems an odd behavior but yeah, the border is not part of the box sizing, even though it's inherent in the input field.. I meant to write "* { border-sizing:  border-box; }" but accidently put it in body. Thanks!

Comment: It's not "almost standards" mode that you were relying on but "quirks" mode. The HTML5 spec says that [in quirks mode, the box-sizing for some form controls is border-box](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/rendering.html#form-controls:quirks-mode), hence matching the fix already identified.

Comment: Thanks again, yomisimie, and sorry for misreading your name! I made sure to get it right in the anser I posted quoting yours.

Answer (score 0):

Since user yomisimie solved it, I'll put it here to close off the thread. "Have you tried to add box-sizing to all elements? Or at least only the ones interacting (div, input)? * { box-sizing: border-box; } – yomisimie"

So the semi-surprising thing is that the borders of INPUT elements are not counted in box sizing (just like any other element) unless you specify { box-sizing: border-box; }. I had meant to do it globally but accidentally put it in BODY instead of a * rule.